# How do convert a relational pandas dataframe to XML using FOR LOOP?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe

I have a question on how I could write an XML documents for some relational dataframes by looping through all of the fields in each table base on their common columns.

I have 3 tables named admission, diagnosis, and dailyintervention. The 3 tables are related via a common column adNo. I will like to export every related record for each adNo

I have imported the following three df

`admission = pd.read_csv(r'Path where the CSV file is stored\File name.csv')`
`diagnosis = pd.read_csv(r'Path where the CSV file is stored\File name.csv')`
`dailyIntervention = pd.read_csv(r'Path where the CSV file is stored\File name.csv')`

**admission**

| adNo | FName | LName | D.O.B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | David | Dean | 23/04/1984 |
| 2002 | John | Snow | 11/02/1988 |
| 2003 | Brat | Jeff | 30/12/1987 |

**diagnosis**

| descID | description | readCode | **adNo** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | BRONCHIOLITIS | XVGF | **2001** |
| 4 | CARDIOMYOPATHY | rtyu | **2001** |
| 6 | VSD | oiug | **2002** |

**dailyIntervention**

| IntID | activitydate | ecg | adNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 02/03/2023 | 1 | 2001 |
| 101 | 04/02/2023 | 1 | 2001 |
| 102 | 03/02/2023 | 0 | 2001 |
| 103 | 02/02/2023 | 0 | 2002 |
| 104 | 05/02/2023 | 1 | 2003 |

I had like write all records into an xml file for every adNo that exist on the **admission** dataframe.

Please see below my desired result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2023-03-10T11:15:55">
    <EpisodeDetails>
        <Admission>
            <adNo>2001</adNo>
            <FName>David</FName>
            <LName>Dean</LName>
            <D.O.B>1984-04-23T00:00:00</D.O.B>
        </Admission>
        <diagnosis>
            <dascID>2</dascID>
            <description>BRONCHIOLITIS</description>
            <readCode>XVGF</readCode>
            <adNo>2001</adNo>
        </diagnosis>
        <diagnosis>
            <dascID>4</dascID>
            <description>CARDIOMYOPATHY</description>
            <readCode>rtyu</readCode>
            <adNo>2001</adNo>
        </diagnosis>
        <dailyIntervention>
            <IntID>100</IntID>
            <activitydate>2023-03-02T00:00:00</activitydate>
            <ecg>1</ecg>
            <adNo>2001</adNo>
        </dailyIntervention>
        <dailyIntervention>
            <IntID>101</IntID>
            <activitydate>2023-02-04T00:00:00</activitydate>
            <ecg>1</ecg>
            <adNo>2001</adNo>
        </dailyIntervention>
        <dailyIntervention>
            <IntID>102</IntID>
            <activitydate>2023-02-03T00:00:00</activitydate>
            <ecg>0</ecg>
            <adNo>2001</adNo>
        </dailyIntervention>
    </EpisodeDetails>
    <EpisodeDetails>
        <Admission>
            <adNo>2002</adNo>
            <FName>John</FName>
            <LName>Snow</LName>
            <D.O.B>1988-02-11T00:00:00</D.O.B>
        </Admission>
        <diagnosis>
            <dascID>6</dascID>
            <description>VSD</description>
            <readCode>oiug</readCode>
            <adNo>2002</adNo>
        </diagnosis>
        <dailyIntervention>
            <IntID>103</IntID>
            <activitydate>2023-02-02T00:00:00</activitydate>
            <ecg>0</ecg>
            <adNo>2002</adNo>
        </dailyIntervention>
    </EpisodeDetails>
    <EpisodeDetails>
        <Admission>
            <adNo>2003</adNo>
            <FName>Brat</FName>
            <LName>Jeff</LName>
            <D.O.B>1987-12-30T00:00:00</D.O.B>
        </Admission>
        <dailyIntervention>
            <IntID>104</IntID>
            <activitydate>2023-02-05T00:00:00</activitydate>
            <ecg>1</ecg>
            <adNo>2002</adNo>
        </dailyIntervention>
    </EpisodeDetails>
</dataroot>
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about which part of the problem you need help with? Is it creating XML itself that is the problem or is it iterating over the admissions to collect the data?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You shouldn't have edited the question that much because now all answers to the previous version don't make sense. Please undo the edit and post a new question.

Comment: You've got now 2 proposals on how to tackle your problem: why don't you take them and make adjustments according to your revised problem? After all, SO isn't a code writing service. You can always ask a new question once you encounter problems with the adjustment.

Comment: Apologies @JackFleeting. I am new to the platform, and that's whys I made this mistake. I have undone the changes. I will post a new question instead. Thanks for your help still.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a task you have here, but it can be done with a combination of pandas, lxml and f-strings. Note that in your actual csvs, some of the spacing, etc., may be different from that in the question, but you can adjust for that, if necessary.

The main building blocks are a series  of templates for the admission, diagnosis and daily intervention sections; these templates are than inserted into their respective episode details containers, which are then inserted into the XML document itself.

Some of this may probably be simplified by adding a helper function or two, but I didn't have to time to try that out, I'm afraid.

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree

#the document skeleton
xml_string = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2023-03-10T11:15:55">   
</dataroot>"""
doc = etree.XML(xml_string.encode())

#create the structure for each episode:
for a in admission['adNo']:
    #create an episode container:
    epi = etree.fromstring('<EpisodeDetails/>')
    #get episode data
    ad_det = admission[admission['adNo ']==a].to_csv(index=False, header=False).strip().split(',')
    #use f-strings to insert the details into an Admission template
    admit = f"""<Admission>
            <adNo>{ad_det[0]}</adNo>
            <FName>{ad_det[1]}</FName>
            <LName>{ad_det[2]}</LName>
            <D.O.B>{ad_det[3]}</D.O.B>            
        </Admission>"""
    #insert this into the Episode container
    epi.append(etree.fromstring(admit))

    #repeat the process for the diagnosis section:
    diags=diagnosis[diagnosis['adNo']==a].to_csv(index=False, header=False).strip().split('\r\n')
    for d in range(len(diags)):
        diag_det = diags[d].split(',')
        if len(diag_det)==4:
            #use the diagnosis template this time:
            diagno = f"""<diagnosis>
                <dascID>{diag_det[0]}</dascID>
                <description>{diag_det[1]}</description>
                <readCode>{diag_det[2]}</readCode>
                <adNo>{diag_det[3]}</adNo>
            </diagnosis>"""
            epi.append(etree.fromstring(diagno))

    #finally, do the same for daily interventions
    intervs = dailyIntervention[dailyIntervention['adNo']==a].to_csv(index=False, header=False).strip().split('\r\n')
    for d in range(len(intervs)):
        interv_det = intervs[d].split(',')
        if len(interv_det)==4:
            daily_i =f""" <dailyIntervention>
            <IntID>{interv_det[0]}</IntID>
            <activitydate>{interv_det[1]}</activitydate>
            <ecg>{interv_det[2]}</ecg>
            <adNo>{interv_det[3]}</adNo>
        </dailyIntervention>"""
            epi.append(etree.fromstring(daily_i))  
    #now append the whole thing to the document itself
    doc.append(epi)

#you need python 3.9 for this:
etree.indent(doc, space='  ')
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

The output should be your expected output.

Comment: Hi @JackFleeting
Thanks for your help with this. I just wanted to check with you on the following, please:

1) If I end up with multiple rows of data on the dailyintervention, and diagnosis table, are you able to automatically feed the len() of the dataframe ( i.e when you used IF() statements) into the building blocks templates for diagnosis and daily intervention sections?

Comment: 2) The element names within the f-strings, I was wondering if it's possible that we iterate through the column names (e.g. admission.columns) and then feed each column names into each element tag in the f-strings instead of manually typing them in.
3) In addition, can't we also iterate the the ad_det, diag_det and interv_det to fetch their individual index to feed into the f-string?

Comment: @Mahmow It's probably possible to do what you want but these are too many questions to answer in comments. You should probably post each of them as a separate question, per SO policy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`DataFrame.to_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xml.html) method to get parts of the XML-structure and then combine them:

```py
import re
from textwrap import indent

re_data = re.compile("</?data>\n?")

dfs = {"Admission": admission, "diagnosis": diagnosis, "dailyIntervention": dailyIntervention}
groups = {}
for name, df in dfs.items():
    for adNo, sdf in df.groupby("adNo"):
        if adNo not in groups:
            groups[adNo] = ""
        xml_str = sdf.to_xml(index=False, row_name=name, xml_declaration=False)
        groups[adNo] += "\n" + re_data.sub("", xml_str).rstrip()

with open("result.xml", "w") as file:
    file.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n')
    file.write('<dataroot>\n')
    for group in groups.values():
        xml_str = "<EpisodeDetails>" + group + "\n</EpisodeDetails>\n"
        file.write(indent(xml_str, " "))
    file.write("</dataroot>")
```

First collect the resp. dataframes in a dictionary with the required tag names as keys. Then group each of the dataframes by `adNo` (the assumption here is that this is the relevant key that glues the dataframes together) and extract the corresponding XML-structure into a string via `.to_xml`, remove the root related parts, and store the combined strings in a dictionary with `adNo` as key. Afterwards join the parts together, embedded into `EpisodeDetails` tags, and add the root level.

If you want the exact datetime format as in the expected output, then convert the resp. columns beforehand, e.g.:

```py
admission["D.O.B"] = (
    pd.to_datetime(admission["D.O.B"], dayfirst=True)
    .dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
)
```

Comment: Your solution got me closer to what I was looking to achieve. But I have just realized few of the nodes were meant to be sub-nodes. I have just amended my question and the desired xml output. Many thanks in anticipation of your help.

Comment: @Mahmow Moving targets isn't cool.

Comment: I am sorry @Timus it won't happen again.