# How to convert a relational dataframes to XML using FOR LOOP?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, for-loop

I have a question in python that I hope someone could help me with.

I have 5 tables named **admission**, **PrimaryDiagnosis**, **otherReason**, **operationOrProcedure**, and **dailyintervention**. The 5 tables are related via a common column **adNo**. I will like to write every related record for each **adNo** into xml file

I have imported the following three dfs

`admission = pd.read_csv(r'Path where the CSV file is stored\File name.csv')`

`PrimaryDiagnosis = pd.read_csv(r'Path where the CSV file is stored\File name.csv')`

`otherReason = pd.read_csv(r'Path where the CSV file is stored\File name.csv')`

`operationOrProcedure = pd.read_csv(r'Path where the CSV file is stored\File name.csv')`

`dailyIntervention = pd.read_csv(r'Path where the CSV file is stored\File name.csv')`

Below are the dataframes displayed:

**admission**

| adNo | FName | LName | D.O.B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | David | Dean | 23/04/1984 |
| 2002 | John | Snow | 11/02/1988 |
| 2003 | Brat | Jeff | 30/12/1987 |

**primaryDiagnosis**

| descID | description | readCode | **adNo** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | BRONCHIOLITIS | XVGF | **2001** |
| 4 | CARDIOMYOPATHY | rtyu | **2002** |
| 6 | VSD | oiug | **2003** |

**otherReason**

| reasonID | description | readCode | **adNo** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | CHEST PAIN | XSfg | **2001** |
| 10 | TRAUMA | aSDF | **2001** |
| 15 | VAD | IOfd | **2003** |

**operationOrProcedure**

| opsID | description | readCode | **adNo** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | CHEST DRAIN | etyr | **2001** |
| 12 | BLOOD TRANS | Qtyu | **2001** |
| 13 | BRAIN OPS | wUOd | **2003** |

**dailyIntervention**

| IntID | activitydate | ecg | adNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 02/03/2023 | 1 | 2001 |
| 101 | 04/02/2023 | 1 | 2001 |
| 102 | 03/02/2023 | 0 | 2001 |
| 103 | 02/02/2023 | 0 | 2002 |
| 104 | 05/02/2023 | 1 | 2003 |

I had like write all records into an xml file for every adNo that exist on the **admission** dataframe.

Please note the order of the nodes:

- All Episodes need to be within the `<dataroot>` node.
- Each `<admission>` needs to be within an `<Episode>` node.
- In each `<episode>` node we have 3 parent nodes

  1. `<admission>` – contains all admission fields.
  2. `<diagnosesAndProcedures>` – contains child nodes of `<primaryDiagnosis>`, `<otherReason>`, and `<operationOrProcedure>`
  3. `<dailyInterventions>` – contains `<dailyIntervention>` nodes for all the associated dailyintervention records.

Below is the desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2023-03-10T11:15:55">
   <Episode adNo="2001">
      <Admission>
         <adNo>2001</adNo>
         <FName>David</FName>
         <LName>Dean</LName>
         <D.O.B>1984-04-23T00:00:00</D.O.B>
      </Admission>
      <diagnosesAndProcedures>
         <primaryDiagnosis>
            <dascID>2</dascID>
            <description>BRONCHIOLITIS</description>
            <readCode>XVGF</readCode>
            <adNo>2001</adNo>
         </primaryDiagnosis>
         <otherReason>
            <reasonID>5</reasonID>
            <description>CHEST PAIN</description>
            <readCode>XSfg</readCode>
            <adNo>2001</adNo>
         </otherReason>
         <otherReason>
            <reasonID>10</reasonID>
            <description>TRAUMA</description>
            <readCode>aSDF</readCode>
            <adNo>2001</adNo>
         </otherReason>
         <operationOrProcedure>
            <opsID>11</opsID>
            <description>CHEST DRAIN</description>
            <readCode>etyr</readCode>
            <adNo>2001</adNo>
         </operationOrProcedure>
         <operationOrProcedure>
            <opsID>12</opsID>
            <description>BLOOD TRANS</description>
            <readCode>Qtyu</readCode>
            <adNo>2001</adNo>
         </operationOrProcedure>
      </diagnosesAndProcedures>
      <dailyInterventions>
         <dailyIntervention>
            <IntID>100</IntID>
            <activitydate>2023-03-02T00:00:00</activitydate>
            <ecg>1</ecg>
            <adNo>2001</adNo>
         </dailyIntervention>
         <dailyIntervention>
            <IntID>101</IntID>
            <activitydate>2023-02-04T00:00:00</activitydate>
            <ecg>1</ecg>
            <adNo>2001</adNo>
         </dailyIntervention>
         <dailyIntervention>
            <IntID>102</IntID>
            <activitydate>2023-02-03T00:00:00</activitydate>
            <ecg>0</ecg>
            <adNo>2001</adNo>
         </dailyIntervention>
      </dailyInterventions>
   </Episode>
   <Episode adNo="2002">
      <Admission>
         <adNo>2002</adNo>
         <FName>John</FName>
         <LName>Snow</LName>
         <D.O.B>1988-02-11T00:00:00</D.O.B>
      </Admission>
      <diagnosesAndProcedures>
         <primaryDiagnosis>
            <dascID>4</dascID>
            <description>CARDIOMYOPATHY</description>
            <readCode>rtyu</readCode>
            <adNo>2002</adNo>
         </primaryDiagnosis>
      </diagnosesAndProcedures>
      <dailyIntervention>
         <IntID>103</IntID>
         <activitydate>2023-02-02T00:00:00</activitydate>
         <ecg>0</ecg>
         <adNo>2002</adNo>
      </dailyIntervention>
   </Episode>
   <Episode adNo="2003">
      <Admission>
         <adNo>2003</adNo>
         <FName>Brat</FName>
         <LName>Jeff</LName>
         <D.O.B>1987-12-30T00:00:00</D.O.B>
      </Admission>
      <diagnosesAndProcedures>
         <primaryDiagnosis>
            <dascID>6</dascID>
            <description>VSD</description>
            <readCode>oiug</readCode>
            <adNo>2003</adNo>
         </primaryDiagnosis>
         <otherReason>
            <reasonID>15</reasonID>
            <description>VAD</description>
            <readCode>IOfd</readCode>
            <adNo>2003</adNo>
         </otherReason>
      </diagnosesAndProcedures>
      <dailyInterventions>
         <dailyIntervention>
            <IntID>104</IntID>
            <activitydate>2023-02-05T00:00:00</activitydate>
            <ecg>1</ecg>
            <adNo>2002</adNo>
         </dailyIntervention>
      </dailyInterventions>
   </Episode>
</dataroot>
```

Comment: Is this a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75716427/12621346)? Why you ask the same question again. What is your own code? Please share your solution and your problem. Stackoverflow is not a Code genrator.

Comment: @Hermann12 There was a mistake in my previous question. So, I posted the correct question

Comment: Imho your expected output is not consistent: The `<Episode adNo= "2002">`  part is missing a closing `</diagnosesAndProcedures>` and the `<dailyInterventions>` and `</dailyInterventions>` tags?

Comment: @Timus Yes you are right, I have fix the issue with the missing tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get a solution to the task using `xml.etree.ElementTree`. Please see my code below with comments:

```
# Import required libraries:
# We import necessary libraries: pandas for reading and manipulating CSV files, Element, SubElement,
# and tostring from xml.etree.ElementTree for building XML structure, and parseString from xml.dom.minidom to prettify
# the XML output."
import pandas as pd
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

# Define the create_xml_node function:
def create_xml_node(parent, tag, value, skip_nan=True):
    if value != "nan" or not skip_nan:
        node = SubElement(parent, tag)
        node.text = value


# Read CSV files into dataframes
# Read CSV files containing the data and store them as pandas dataframes.
admission = pd.read_csv("data/episodeDetails.csv")
primaryDiagnosis = pd.read_csv("data/primaryDiagnosis.csv")
otherReason = pd.read_csv("data/otherReason.csv")
operationOrProcedure = pd.read_csv("data/operationOrProcedure.csv")
coMorbidity = pd.read_csv("data/coMorbidity.csv")
dailyintervention = pd.read_csv("data/dailyIntervention.csv")


# Convert adNo column to string dtype
# Convert the 'adNo' column to a string data type for all dataframes to ensure proper matching and comparison.
admission["adNo"] = admission["adNo"].astype(str)
primaryDiagnosis["adNo"] = primaryDiagnosis["adNo"].astype(str)
otherReason["adNo"] = otherReason["adNo"].astype(str)
operationOrProcedure["adNo"] = operationOrProcedure["adNo"].astype(str)
coMorbidity["adNo"] = coMorbidity["adNo"].astype(str)
dailyintervention["adNo"] = dailyintervention["adNo"].astype(str)


# Create a dictionary of dataframes
# Create a dictionary that maps node names to their corresponding dataframes for easy access
dfs = {
    "admission": admission,
    "primaryDiagnosis": primaryDiagnosis,
    "otherReason": otherReason,
    "operationOrProcedure": operationOrProcedure,
    "coMorbidity": coMorbidity,
    "dailyintervention": dailyintervention,
}


# Create the root element
# Create the root element for the XML document, including the XML namespace and the generated timestamp.
dataroot = Element(
    "dataroot",
    {
        "xmlns:od": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata",
        "generated": "2023-03-10T11:15:55",
    },
)


# Group the dataframes by adNo
# Group the 'admission' dataframe by 'adNo' to process one episode at a time.
grouped = admission.groupby("adNo")


# Loop through each group and create an Episode element
# For each unique 'adNo', create an 'Episode' element with the 'adNo' attribute.

# Create the 'Admission' node under the 'Episode' node,
# and populate its child elements with the columns from the 'admission' dataframe.
for adNo, group in grouped:
    episode = SubElement(dataroot, "Episode", {"adNo": adNo})

    # Create and populate admission_element
    admission_element = SubElement(episode, "admission")
    for column_name, value in group.iloc[0].items():
        if column_name != "adNo":
            create_xml_node(admission_element, column_name, str(value))

    # Create the 'diagnosesAndProcedures' node under the 'Episode' node. Loop through the node_order list
    # (which contains the desired order of nodes), and for each node, find the related records in the corresponding
    # dataframe. If there are related records, create a new element for each record and populate its child elements
    # with the columns from the dataframe.'

    # Create and populate diagnosesAndProcedures_element
    diagnosesAndProcedures_element = SubElement(episode, "diagnosesAndProcedures")
    for node in [
        "primaryDiagnosis",
        "otherReason",
        "coMorbidity",
        "operationOrProcedure",
    ]:
        df = dfs[node]
        node_group = df[df["adNo"] == adNo]
        for _, row in node_group.iterrows():
            record_element = SubElement(diagnosesAndProcedures_element, node)
            for column_name, value in row.items():
                if column_name != "adNo":
                    create_xml_node(record_element, column_name, str(value))

    # Create the 'dailyInterventions' node under the 'Episode' node. Find the related records in the 'dailyintervention'
    # dataframe. If there are related records, create a new 'dailyIntervention' element for each record and populate
    # its child elements with the columns from the dataframe.

    # Create and populate dailyInterventions_element
    dailyInterventions_element = SubElement(episode, "dailyInterventions")
    df = dfs["dailyintervention"]
    node_group = df[df["adNo"] == adNo]
    for _, row in node_group.iterrows():
        dailyIntervention_element = SubElement(
            dailyInterventions_element, "dailyIntervention"
        )
        for column_name, value in row.items():
            if column_name != "adNo":
                create_xml_node(dailyIntervention_element, column_name, str(value))


# Convert the root element to an XML string
# Create an XML string from the root element, including the XML version and encoding declaration.
xml_string = b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' + tostring(
    dataroot, encoding="UTF-8"
)


# To indent the nodes in the XML output, you can use the xml.dom.minidom library to parse and prettify the XML string.
# Parse the XML string with the parseString function from the xml.dom.minidom library and then use the toprettyxml method
# to create a prettified version of the XML string with indentation.

# Parse and prettify the XML string using minidom
dom = parseString(xml_string)
pretty_xml_string = dom.toprettyxml(indent="   ")

# Write the prettified XML string to a file
with open("brhc_picanetClientImport.xml", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    f.write(pretty_xml_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell :

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$xmlFile = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$admissionFilename = 'c:\temp\admission.csv'
$primaryFilename = 'c:\temp\primary.csv'
$otherFilename = 'c:\temp\other.csv'
$operationFilename = 'c:\temp\operation.csv'
$dailyFilename = 'c:\temp\daily.csv'

$admission = Import-Csv -Path $admissionFilename
$primary = Import-Csv -Path $primaryFilename
$other = Import-Csv -Path $otherFilename
$operation = Import-Csv -Path $operationFilename
$daily = Import-Csv -Path $dailyFilename

$episodes = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Join(
    $admission,
    $primary,
    [System.Func[Object,string]] {param ($admission);$admission.adNo},
    [System.Func[Object,string]]{param ($primary);$primary.adNo},
    [System.Func[Object,Object,Object]]{
        param ($admission,$primary);
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        admission = $admission;
        primary = $primary}
    }
)

$episodes = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Join(
    $episodes,
    $other,
    [System.Func[Object,string]] {param ($episodes);$episodes.admission.adNo},
    [System.Func[Object,string]]{param ($other);$other.adNo},
    [System.Func[Object,Object,Object]]{
        param ($episodes,$other);
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        admission = $episodes.admission;
        primary = $episodes.primary;
        other = $other}
     }
)
$episodes = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Join(
    $episodes,
    $operation,
    [System.Func[Object,string]] {param ($episodes);$episodes.admission.adNo},
    [System.Func[Object,string]]{param ($operation);$operation.adNo},
    [System.Func[Object,Object,Object]]{
        param ($episodes,$operation);
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        admission = $episodes.admission;
        primary = $episodes.primary;
        other = $episodes.other;
        operation = $operation}
     }
)
$episodes = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Join(
    $episodes,
    $daily,
    [System.Func[Object,string]] {param ($episodes);$episodes.admission.adNo},
    [System.Func[Object,string]]{param ($daily);$daily.adNo},
    [System.Func[Object,Object,Object]]{
        param ($episodes,$daily);
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        admission = $episodes.admission;
        primary = $episodes.primary;
        other = $episodes.other;
        operation = $episodes.operation;
        daily = $daily}
     }
)
$episodes | Format-List

$xmlIdent = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="">
</dataroot>
'@
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($xmlIdent)

$date = [DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
$root = $xDoc.Root
$root.SetAttributeValue("generated", $date)

$adNoGroups = $episodes | Group-Object -Property {$_.admission.adNo}
$adNoGroups
foreach($episode in $adNoGroups)
{
   $xEpisode = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Episode'))  
   $xEpisode.SetAttributeValue("adNo", $episode.Name)
   $root.Add($xEpisode)

   $xAdmission = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Admission'))
   $adNo = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Admission'), $episode.Name)
   $xAdmission.Add($adNo)
   $fName = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('FName'), $episode.Group.admission[0].FName)
   $xAdmission.Add($fName)
   $lName = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('LName'), $episode.Group.admission[0].LName)
   $xAdmission.Add($lName)
   $dob = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('D.O.B'), $episode.Group.admission[0].'D.O.B')
   $xAdmission.Add($dob)

   $xEpisode.Add($xAdmission)

   $xdiagnoses = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('diagnosesAndProcedures'))

   $xprimary = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('primaryDiagnosis'))
   $descID = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('descIC'), $episode.Group.primary[0].descID)
   $xprimary.Add($descID)
   $desc = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('description'), $episode.Group.primary[0].description)
   $xprimary.Add($desc)
   $code = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('readCode'), $episode.Group.primary[0].readCode)
   $xprimary.Add($code)
   $adNo = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('adNo'), $episode.Group.primary[0].adNo)
   $xprimary.Add($adNo)
     
   $xdiagnoses.Add($xprimary)

   $otherGroups = $episode.Group | Group-Object -Property {$_.other.reasonID}
   $otherGroups | Format-List

   foreach($other in $otherGroups)
   {
      $xother = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('otherReason'))
      $reasonID = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('reasonID'), $other.Name)
      $xother.Add($reasonID)
      $desc = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('description'), $other.Group.other[0].description)
      $xother.Add($desc)
      $code = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('readCode'), $episode.Group.other[0].readCode)
      $xother.Add($code)
      $adNo = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('adNo'), $episode.Group.other[0].adNo)
      $xother.Add($adNo)


      $xdiagnoses.Add($xother)
   }


   $operationGroups = $episode.Group | Group-Object -Property {$_.operation.opsID}
   $operationGroups | Format-List

   foreach($operation in $operationGroups)
   {
      $xoperation = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('operationOrProcedure'))
      $opsID = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('reasonID'), $operation.Name)
      $xoperation.Add($opsID)
      $desc = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('description'), $other.Group.operation[0].description)
      $xoperation.Add($desc)
      $code = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('readCode'), $episode.Group.operation[0].readCode)
      $xoperation.Add($code)
      $adNo = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('adNo'), $episode.Group.operation[0].adNo)
      $xoperation.Add($adNo)


      $xdiagnoses.Add($xoperation)
   }
   
   $xEpisode.Add($xdiagnoses)

   $xdailys = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('dailyInterventions'))

   $dailysGroups = $episode.Group | Group-Object -Property {$_.daily.IntID}
   $dailysGroups | Format-List

   foreach($daily in $dailysGroups)
   {
      $xdaily = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('dailyIntervention'))

      $intID = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('IntID'), $daily.Name)
      $xdaily.Add($intID)
      $date = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('activitydate'), $other.Group.operation[0].activitydate)
      $xdaily.Add($date)
      $ecg = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('ecg'), $episode.Group.operation[0].ecg)
      $xdaily.Add($ecg)
      $adNo = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('adNo'), $episode.Group.operation[0].adNo)
      $xdaily.Add($adNo)


      $xdailys.Add($xdaily)
   }

   $xEpisode.Add($xdailys)
}

$xDoc.Save($xmlFile)
```